# How to dynamically switch modes with CodeMirror?

Tags: codemirror

How to dynamically switch modes with CodeMirror?

I have the default set, but need to switch it.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Something like this would help you.

First, set CodeMirror:

```js
this.editor = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(document.getElementById("textAreaCodeMirror"), {
    lineNumbers: true,
    matchBrackets: true,
    styleActiveLine: true,
    theme:"eclipse",
    mode:language
});
```

Then, to change the mode

```js
this.editor.setOption("mode", language);
```

Comment: @Ponumdi how can use multiple parameters in setOption ?

Comment: @FadiAkkad ASAIK only one option can be set. Custom function can be created for setting multiple options

Answer (score 14):

If this is CodeMirror 2 or 3, use `setOption("mode", <new mode>)` (docs for [`setOption`](http://codemirror.net//doc/manual.html#setOption), [`"mode"`](http://codemirror.net//doc/manual.html#option_mode)).

For CodeMirror 1, use the [`setParser` method](http://codemirror.net/1/manual.html#methods).

Comment: What about CodeMirror 3?