# Multiple text-areas being added after an update event

Tags: javascript, html, codemirror

I am making a simple code editor using codemirror. I am at the last stage but a bug has occurred which I am not able to get my heads around.

I have a `select` html tag with three options:

```
<select class="language" id="lang" onclick="update()">
  <option value="javascript">JavaScript</option>
  <option value="python">Python</option>
  <option value="python">C</option>
</select>
```

And my `update()` function is:

```
function update() {
  var select = $('#lang').val();
  var editor = CodeMirror.fromTextArea($('#text'), {
      mode: select,
      theme: "blackboard",
      });
}
update();
```

Now what happens is that everytime I select a different option from the dropdown, a new Code editor is added below the previous one.

Do you have some idea where I am going wrong in the code and how I can workaround?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your JS to this:

```js
let editor;
function update() {
  var select = $('#lang').val();
  editor = editor ?? CodeMirror.fromTextArea($('#text'), {
      theme: "blackboard",
  });
  editor.setOption('mode', select);
}
update();
```

This makes it so if `editor` already exists, it is not created again, but instead re-used.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! After modifying as you said, it is now working as expected but now the editor is not being updated. Like if I choose some other language, the syntax highlighting remains as that of the previous one.

Comment: I've found the solution to that problem here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6130563/how-to-dynamically-switch-modes-with-codemirror . Changed my answer accordingly.

Comment: Please note you made this mistake (at least in the code you've shown here): `<option value="python">C</option>` value and displayed language don't match.

Comment: Thank you! It solves my problem now! And for the value of python for C, I was just testing it :)